# In R: ordering values from 2 DF columns for use in ratio for each row

Tags: r

I want to calculate ratios for each row in a data frame using values from two columns for each row.  The data are anatomical measurements from paired muscles, and I need to calculate a ratio of the measurement of one muscle to the measurement of the other.  Each row is an individual specimen, and each of the 2 columns in question has measurements for one of the 2 muscles.  Which of the two muscles is largest varies among individuals (rows), so I need to figure out how to write a script that always picks the smaller value, which may be in either column, for the numerator, and that always picks the larger values, which also can be in either column, for the denominator, rather than simply dividing all values of one column by values of the other.  This might be simple, but I'm not so good with coding yet.

This doesn't work: 
ratio <- DF$1/DF$2

I assume that what I need would loop through each row doing something like this:

ratio <- which.min(c(DF$1, DF$2))/which.max(c(DF$1, DF$2))

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are only dealing with positive values, you could consider something like this:

```
# example data:
df <- data.frame(x = abs(rnorm(100)), y = abs(rnorm(100)))
# sorting the two columns so that the smaller always appears in the first     
# column:
df_sorted <- t(apply(df,1, sort))
# dividing the first col. by the second col. 
ratio <- df_sorted[,1]/df_sorted[,2]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
ifelse(df[,1] > df[,2], df[,2]/df[,1], df[,1]/df[,2])
```